# EF Core : duplicate values sent to database

Tags: c#, csv, entity-framework-core, csvhelper

My code:

```
using var context = new NorthwindContext();
        
var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    Delimiter = ";",
    HeaderValidated = null,
    MissingFieldFound = null
};

using var reader = new StreamReader("csvfile.csv");
using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, csvConfig);

var records = csv.GetRecords<Employees>().ToList();

foreach (var item in records) 
     Console.WriteLine($"{item.FirstName} {item.LastName}"); //results as expected

context.AddRange(records);

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
await context.DisposeAsync();
```

Csv file:

```
FirstName;LastName
John;Doe
```

Results:

John Doe is saved twice in the database.

Expected results:

John Doe is saved only once in the database.

Comment: Can you try HasHeaderRecord = true, inside new CsvConfiguration?

Comment: It looks like you're not skipping over the title row.

Comment: Thats possible, but then why in VS it has 1 element, but on the database end 2 elements? Edit - results still the same - values duplicated.

Comment: troubleshoot by 1. Taking away the AddRange(records) and seeing if there is any other code that inserts into your db. 2. Use Add inside your foreach loop and debug it.

Comment: Already tried using `Add` and `Add` inside `foreach` loop - exact same results. Except there was exception while using only `Add` (can't insert `List` inside database that way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a strange one.  I tried it and got the same duplicate results. I only got one John Doe if I created the `records` list in code without using CsvHelper.  I finally got a clue when I noticed one of the records had a value for `ReportsTo` with the EmployeeId of the first record. Apparently CsvHelper's `AutoMap` is also creating an `Employees` record for the `ReportsToNavigation` property. I would think that is a possible bug in CsvHelper. My only solution would be to manually map the fields that you need.

```cs
using var context = new NorthwindContext();
        
var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    Delimiter = ";",
    HeaderValidated = null,
    MissingFieldFound = null
};

using var reader = new StreamReader("csvfile.csv");
using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, csvConfig);

csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<EmployeesMap>();

var records = csv.GetRecords<Employees>().ToList();

foreach (var item in records) 
     Console.WriteLine($"{item.FirstName} {item.LastName}"); //results as expected

context.AddRange(records);

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
await context.DisposeAsync();
```

```cs
public sealed class EmployeesMap : ClassMap<Employees>
{
    public EmployeesMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.FirstName);
        Map(m => m.LastName);
    }
}
```